# How to create group of buttons when i clicked one button (add button) in objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I am new to iOS development. I am creating one application which contains one button, which acts like an add button. If I click that button, I want to create a set of three buttons. When I click the add button, every time these buttons also want to create next to previous buttons. I need an idea or sample code for that. This is my code:

```
-(void) addBtnAct
{

    [self.view addSubview:sizeDropDownBtn];
    deleteBtn.hidden=YES;
    [sizeDropDownBtn addSubview:sizeDropDownBtnLbl];
    [self.view addSubview:weightDropDownBtn];
    [weightDropDownBtn addSubview:weightDropDownBtnLbl];
    [self.view addSubview:quantityTxtFld];
    [quantityTxtFld addSubview:quantityLbl];
    sizeDropDownBtn.frame = CGRectMake(10, 190, 86, 40);
    weightDropDownBtn.frame = CGRectMake(110, 190, 86, 40);
    quantityTxtFld.frame = CGRectMake(220, 190, 86, 40);
    quantityLbl.frame = CGRectMake(10, 12, 100, 15);
    sizeDropDownBtnLbl.frame = CGRectMake(20, 12, 100, 15);
    weightDropDownBtnLbl.frame = CGRectMake(10,12, 100, 15);
```

Sorry for my bad English. Thank you.

Comment: But could u explain that do u want to add 3 buttons everytym or do they can vary ?

Comment: Thanks for response @vikingosegundo . i want to create 3 buttons every time.

Comment: @Manimaran: I did not respond. I just formatted your question.

Comment: ok. i am sorry. thanks for @IronManGill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi plese try following code:

```
int x=10;
int y=10;

for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{

  CGRect frame = CGRectMake(10, y, 280, 40);
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        button.frame = frame;
        button.tag=i;
        [button setTitle:(NSString *)@"new button" forState:(UIControlState)UIControlStateNormal];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"temp.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.view addSubview:button];
y+=45;
}
```

hope this code will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Then for this you could simply use a looping statement in your UIButton's method. In the loop add the Buttons according to the x and y coordinates . Keep changing the x and y coordinates every time the loop executes. This will prevent them from overlapping each other.

Comment: Thanks for your help IronManGill . Can you give me some sample code.